# NodeJS : How to redirect to a different domain name from a route

Tags: angularjs, node.js, routes

I am building a MEAN Stack application and my API runs on `app.example.com` and my frontend runs on `web.example.com`.
I am trying to build an email verification system, which will send an email to the user. The link I send is `app.example.com/email-verification/${URL}` which is one of my routes in my application. After verifying the user I want him to go (in frontend) from `web.example.com/login` (Mind you this is angular's routing) to `web.example.com/dashboard`. How do I achieve this? Is this actually possible?

Comment: the first thing you should do is to allow cross-domain-origin and if possible you should build your link using the web application and not the web api. For the routing part take a look about '$location' service

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand the question, but I think it's pretty simple:

```
$location.path('/dashboard');
```

User fills the form (Angular-front) -> User clicks the email (In the url you can put a param with the email encripted) -> The controller check the param and call to the NODE API method that verify email -> When angular front get a successful response from api : Login method and $location.path('/dashboard');

Sorry my english :P

Comment: I don't think we have $location object in NodeJS. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't understand you (Frontender over here :S). Anyway, I think that redirect is more usually done in the angular controller. I'll edit my response with an scheme. Anyway I'm not an expert.